# ssh login to strato vserver fails

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login

I recently got problems login into my strato vserver with ssh. Using the mac terminal my Internet-Connection broke up for 1 second. Login in again the server throws back the following error message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I can connect to the server through a different host name. A reboot doesn't solve the problem. What is the reasons therefore? Are there any ssh deny list or ssh session? Where may I find them to delete them?

Comment: Try with `ssh -vvv yourhost` to see more debug information.

Comment: Reinstalled my vserver. It seems the whole server is crashing. It happend again while i was logged in. Can not run any tasks on the shell. Error: "Cannot allocate memory". Login is possible after reboot now. However I cannot find out anything in the logs. It's a ubuntu server. Any ideas in which logs server I may find out reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often this is caused by an entry in `/etc/hosts.deny` due to some previous failed login.

Comment: /etc/hosts.deny doesn't exist. Seems to be a server crash for any reason